# Shiny - Plotting overrides the previous plots

Tags: r, shiny, visualization

I'm trying to create an App with Shiny that allows users to contrast different columns of a dataset graphically. For that, I have created a Shiny application that allows users to choose the parameters they want to compare with each other, and the application generates charts with all the permutations of these parameters.

However, I found that whenever I plot more than one chart, the last plot overrides all of the previous ones.

This is what I tried, on the server side:

```
observeEvent(c(input$Update_Selection), ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    showNotification("Updated Plotting Parameters")
    
    permutations <- combn(input$selection_tags, 2)
    output$plots <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:ncol(permutations), function(i) {
      plotname <- paste0("plot", i)
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 512, width = 512)
    })

    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })

  for (i in 1:ncol(permutations)) {
    local({
      plotname <- paste0("plot", i)
      
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        plot(dataset[[permutations[1, i]]][1:input$samplesize], dataset[[permutations[2, i]]][1:input$samplesize],
             xlab = permutations[1, i], 
             ylab = permutations[2, i]
        )
      })
      })
    }
  })
```

This makes all plots look like the last plot. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Try with adding `i <- i`, i.e. do `local({ i <- i; plotname <- .... })`. Or switch to `lapply` instead of the for loop, which also allows to get rid of `local()`. The issue is due to lazy evaluation, i.e. inside your loop you only create a blueprints which still need to be filled with a value for i.  And only at the time when the plot is rendered is the code evaluated and only at this time is a value assigned to i. However, as the for loop was already processed at this time `i` is equal to the last value of the counter aka `ncol(permutations)`.